# TYPO3 v9: How to register a custom validator in backend

Tags: php, yaml, typo3

I am in the process of writing my own custom form validator, which checks if a submitted email already is in the database.

The Typo3 documentation explains pretty well, how you can do they here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Validators/Index.html

Now the only problem I face is how to add my custom validator to the backend so the admin will be able to select it from the list of validators and maybe add a custom error message as an argument.

I already registered a custom finisher. I believe registering a custom validator should be similar, just writing the right YAML configuration. However, I do not find any examples of how to do that.

How to properly register a custom validator in a YAML config file so it shows up in the backend?

---

Edit:

to avoid confusion :), I want to register the validator in the backend so the administrator is able to select it from the list of validators:

[image: example]

Comment: The example of how to register a validator is at the bottom of your linked page: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Validators/Index.html#custom-validator-implementations

Comment: that is an example of how to register it directly in the form yaml configuration file. I want to register my custom validator in the backend so the administrator of the page is able to select the validator from the dropdown list of validators

Comment: The last example yes, but the first two examples are for registering it for the backend wizard.

Comment: No, it is not. The first two examples explain how to register a validator so you can use it in the YAML configuration directly. This is fine. However, I want to be able to select it from the selectbox in the backend. The two examples are just the first step. When writing a finisher you have to also add the select options in the editor, include the BaseCollectionEditorsMixin, include the icon,...
I believe you have to do something similar for the validators, I just did not find any examples of how to do that.
I tried it with just the two examples from the posted link. My validator is...

Comment: ... useable, but it does not show up in the form builder in backend.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with EXT:form, but are you registering some setup modifications for the *backend*? https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Configuration/Index.html#yaml-registration-for-the-backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You have to *"yaml yourself to hell"*.

Long answer:

In addition to the validators definition, you have to add your validator to the ***propertyCollections*** and ***selectOptions*** of all form fields you want the validator to appear. Selective, as e.g. a phone number validator does not make any sense in an email-field.

Have a look into the yaml configuration of the "Text" element:

1. Adding a new option to the options dropdown --> see the [following lines](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/241e6a0b3037fe79cba1efeed775461a71c7a695/typo3/sysext/form/Configuration/Yaml/FormElements/Text.yaml#L79)
2. Adding validators to the propertyCollection --> see the [following lines](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/241e6a0b3037fe79cba1efeed775461a71c7a695/typo3/sysext/form/Configuration/Yaml/FormElements/Text.yaml#L115)

So you need to add a new option to the options dropdown and add your validator to the propertyCollection.

A working real life example, which adds four custom validators the the Date field:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formElementsDefinition:
            Date:
              implementationClassName: 'Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\FormElements\Date'
              properties:
                modifier: 'date'
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  900:
                    selectOptions:
                      30:
                        value: MinAge
                        label: 'Min Age'
                      35:
                        value: MaxAge
                        label: 'Max Age'
                      40:
                        value: MinDate
                        label: 'Min date from today'
                      50:
                        value: MaxDate
                        label: 'Max date from today'
                predefinedDefaults:
                  properties:
                    minage: ''
                    maxage: ''
                    minDateDays: null
                    maxDateDays: null
                propertyCollections:
                  validators:
                    2000:
                      identifier: MinAge
                      editors:
                        100:
                          identifier: header
                          templateName: Inspector-CollectionElementHeaderEditor
                          label: 'Min age (in years)'
                        250:
                          identifier: minAge
                          templateName: Inspector-TextEditor
                          label: 'Min age'
                          placeholder: 'Years (e.g. 17) as integer'
                          propertyPath: options.minage
                          propertyValidators:
                            10: Integer
                          additionalElementPropertyPaths:
                            10: properties.minage
                        350:
                          identifier: errorMessageCObjUid
                          templateName: Inspector-Typo3WinBrowserEditor
                          label: Error message relation
                          buttonLabel: formEditor.elements.ContentElement.editor.contentElement.buttonLabel
                          browsableType: tt_content
                          iconIdentifier: mimetypes-x-content-text
                          propertyPath: options.errorMessageCObjUid
                        9999:
                          identifier: removeButton
                          templateName: Inspector-RemoveElementEditor
                    2050:
                      identifier: MaxAge
                      editors:
                        100:
                          identifier: header
                          templateName: Inspector-CollectionElementHeaderEditor
                          label: 'Max age (in years)'
                        250:
                          identifier: maxAge
                          templateName: Inspector-TextEditor
                          label: 'Max age'
                          placeholder: 'Years (e.g. 25) as integer'
                          propertyPath: options.maxage
                          propertyValidators:
                            10: Integer
                          additionalElementPropertyPaths:
                            10: properties.maxage
                        350:
                          identifier: errorMessageCObjUid
                          templateName: Inspector-Typo3WinBrowserEditor
                          label: Error message relation
                          buttonLabel: formEditor.elements.ContentElement.editor.contentElement.buttonLabel
                          browsableType: tt_content
                          iconIdentifier: mimetypes-x-content-text
                          propertyPath: options.errorMessageCObjUid
                        9999:
                          identifier: removeButton
                          templateName: Inspector-RemoveElementEditor
                    2100:
                      identifier: MinDate
                      editors:
                        100:
                          identifier: header
                          templateName: Inspector-CollectionElementHeaderEditor
                          label: 'Min date from today'
                        250:
                          identifier: minDateDays
                          templateName: Inspector-TextEditor
                          label: 'Today + X days'
                          placeholder: 'Number of days'
                          propertyPath: options.minDateDays
                          propertyValidators:
                            10: Integer
                          additionalElementPropertyPaths:
                            10: properties.minDateDays
                        9999:
                          identifier: removeButton
                          templateName: Inspector-RemoveElementEditor
                    2200:
                      identifier: MaxDate
                      editors:
                        100:
                          identifier: header
                          templateName: Inspector-CollectionElementHeaderEditor
                          label: 'Max date from today'
                        250:
                          identifier: maxDateDays
                          templateName: Inspector-TextEditor
                          label: 'Today + X days'
                          placeholder: 'Number of days'
                          propertyPath: options.maxDateDays
                          propertyValidators:
                            10: Integer
                          additionalElementPropertyPaths:
                            10: properties.maxDateDays
                        9999:
                          identifier: removeButton
                          templateName: Inspector-RemoveElementEditor
```